# Rails - adding new field to inherting class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have Student model, inheriting User model

> class Student < User

if I add new field to Student, its not showing up. All I see is replica of User fields in Student table.

> rails g model User email:string name:string gender:boolean 
> rails g model Student age:integer
>
> rake db:migrate

User model :

> class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
> validates :email, :name, presence: true 
> end

then I replaced 
 class Student < ActiveRecord::Base with

> class Student < User 
> end

now the :age field is replaced by :email, :name, :gender fields in Student table, I don't have access to :age field anymore

Student should have User fields as well as additional fields of its own. 
how do I achieve this?

Comment: What you have there is single table inheritance http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

Comment: can you show us the code that actually adds the 'field' you can't see (show the first few lines of your Student model for example) and maybe a little  more of the User model, so we can see if its activerecord or just a plain ruby class.

Comment: @Phil - I tried adding one more field through migration, still I don't see any field added to Student table, can you tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're getting confused between `tables` and `models` in Rails.

As mentioned in the comments, you have a [Single Table Inheritance](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/) setup; you'll have a single `users` table which can be extrapolated to different classes (models) using the `Type` attribute:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | type | other | user | attributes | created_at | updated_at
end

#app/models/student.rb
class Student < User
   # uses "users" table

   def custom_method
     #=> Will only appear with @student.custom_method (IE @user.custom_method will not exist)
   end
end
```

This means that you don't have two tables in this instance; `Student` will be using the `User` table.

If you wish to use custom attributes in the `Student` model, you're able to (outlined above). Ultimately, with STI, you have to use the same table for all the inherited models. If you need to add extra attributes, you're going to have to append to the "parent" table.

--

> Student should have User fields as well as additional fields of its own

If there are a lot of attributes, you'll have to set up another table to store them, and then associate the two models. It will be messier, but it's better than storing huge amounts of empty cells in a single table:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile
end

#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :student
end
```

This is how we store our users in some of our apps:

[image]

This gives us the ability to call `@user.profile.homepage` etc, or if we wanted to delegate it:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile
   delegate :homepage, to: :profile, prefix: true #-> @user.profile_homepage
end
```